# Going to Bookmarks in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I know I can toggle (set and clear) bookmarks in Android Studio (I have 2.2.2) using F11.     But is there any similarly simple way to just **go to** the next bookmark?  The only way I've found to go to the next bookmark is buried in the navigation menu -  Navigate > Bookmarks > Next Bookmark.   Is there some way to assign a function key to that?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is no default shortcut to go to next bookmark. Though you can set one in Preferences.

To do that go to **Preferences** > **Keymap** then under **Main menu** > **Navigate** > **Bookmarks** you can set the desired keyboard shortcut for various action. (You can also search for `bookmark` keyword in the search bar of Preferences Window to navigate directly.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: For Windows 3.x, Keymap is under Settings (File/Settings/Keymap). Double click the Next Bookmark/Previous Bookmark to add a new shortcut.

Answer (score 28):

Using `Go to next bookmark` for the projects with lots of bookmarks maybe not useful so much.

My suggestion is using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to see the full list of bookmarks in summery and go directly to the one you need.

Also in addition to <kbd>F11</kbd>, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> can be a good choice to set a Mnemonic single address code for each bookmark and find them directly with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `NUMBER`.

In mac systems, these 3 keys replace with <kbd>F3</kbd> - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> - <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

step 1: Shift + F11 
step 2: Alt + Up/Down

That's it.

Answer (score 5):

On Mac and Android Studio 4 You can do the following

**Setting A Book Mark**

```
Right click on the line counter pane and set bookmark
```

[image]

**Clear The Bookmark**

```
Right click on the line counter pane and clear the bookmark
```

[image]

**Navigate To Bookmarks**

```
Go to Navigate -> Bookmarks -> Show Bookmarks
```

[image]

**Navigate To Bookmarks (Another Way)**

```
On the right side you will see a black horizontal line marker for the bookmark you can click on that to jump to the bookmark
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add two new buttons on toolbar that are previous and next bookmark actions in this way: perform click with rigth mouse button on toolbar and select "customize menus and toolbars". Select "main toolbar" and click on an position that you want to add new buttons. Click on "Add After" button and select command "next and previous bookmark" from navigate menu. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac User Press:command + f3

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl + Shift + 1` to add a bookmark with the label `1`

`Ctrl + 1` to go to that bookmark

You can use the same process with other numbers as well. for example, `Ctrl+Shift+2` will add the bookmark with label `2`, and so on...